# SelectOneMenu dependientes en Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Tengo una base de datos con 4 tablas (*Solicitud, Provincia, Municipio, Pueblo*) donde tengo que añadir una solicitud. Creo 3 *SelectOneMenu* dependientes para escoger la Provincia según lo que se seleccione se debe actualizar el SelectOneMenu de Municipio y así debe pasar con Pueblos, pero cuando se selecciona un Municipio no se actualiza Pueblo.

Si me pudieran ayudar se lo agradezco.

Este es mi código:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plusthick" id="addSolicBtn" value="Añadir solicitud"  update=":solicDetail1" ajax="true" 
                     oncomplete="PF('$solicDetail1').show()" style="margin-left: 10px;" /> 
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="solicDetail1" widgetVar="$solicDetail1" header="Añadir solicitud" hideEffect="explode" appendTo="@(body)" 
          resizable="false" draggable="false" closeOnEscape="true" modal="true"> 
    <h:form id="formDialog">  
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2"> 
            <h:outputLabel for="nomb_pers" value="Nombre de la persona: *" />  
            <p:inputText id="nomb_pers" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectsolicitud.nomb_pers}" 
                         label="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellidos" style="width:135px"> 
                <p:keyFilter regEx="/[A-Z .\\á-ú]/i"/>
            </p:inputText>

            <h:outputLabel for="ci" value="Carnet de identidad: *" />  
            <p:inputMask id="ci" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectsolicitud.ci}" mask="99999999999" 
                         placeholder="Carnet de identidad" style="width:135px"/>  

            <h:outputLabel for="direccion" value="Dirección: *" />  
            <p:inputText id="direccion" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectsolicitud.direccion}" 
                         label="direccion" placeholder="Dirección" style="width:135px"/> 

            <h:outputLabel for="telefono" value="Teléfono: "/>   
            <p:inputText id="telefono" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectsolicitud.telefono}" 
                         label="Nombre" placeholder="Número de teléfono" style="width:135px">
                <p:keyFilter regEx="/[\d\-]/"/>
            </p:inputText>

            <h:outputLabel for="fecha" value="Fecha de solicitud: *"/>
            <p:calendar id="fecha" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectsolicitud.fecha}"  pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"
                        navigator="true" mode="popup" placeholder="Fecha de solicitud" locale="es"
                        style="width:500px"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="tipo_afect" value="Tipo de afectación: *" />  
            <p:inputText id="tipo_afect" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectsolicitud.tipo_afect}" 
                         label="tipo_afectación" placeholder="Tipo de afectación" style="width:135px"/> 

            <h:outputLabel for="cult_danado" value="Cultivo dañado: *" />  
            <p:inputText id="cult_danado" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectsolicitud.cult_danado}" 
                         label="cultivo_dañado" placeholder="Cultivo dañado" style="width:135px"/> 

            <h:outputLabel for="zona_afect" value="Zona afectada: *" />  
            <p:inputText id="zona_afect" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectsolicitud.zona_afect}" 
                         label="zona_afectada" placeholder="Zona afectada" style="width:135px" />                                             

            <h:outputLabel for="provlist" value="Provincia: *"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="provlist" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectprov}" style="width:130px">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione la provincia" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectItemsOneProvincia}" />
                <p:ajax update="munlist"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputLabel for="munlist" value="Municipio: *"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="munlist" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectmun}" style="width:130px">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione el municipio" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectItemsOneMunicipio}" />
                <p:ajax update="pueblolist"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputLabel for="pueblolist" value="Pueblo: *"/>
            <p:row> 
                <p:column>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="pueblolist" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectpueblo}" style="width:130px; margin-top: 10px" required="true" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione el pueblo" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectItemsOnePueblo}" />
                        <p:ajax update="pueblolist"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:commandButton value="Añadir" process="@form" id="AddButtonId" ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-plus" 
                             update=":formDialog:msgs" actionListener="#{solicitudManagedBean.addSolicitud()}" />  


        </p:panelGrid>  
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
                
                
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SolicitudManagedBean {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of SolicitudManagedBean
 */
    private String selectprov;
    private String selectmun;
    private String selectpueblo;
    private List<SelectItem> selectItemsOneProvincia;
    private List<SelectItem> selectItemsOneMunicipio;
    private List<SelectItem> selectItemsOnePueblo;
    private Solicitud selectsolicitud;
    private final PuebloDAO pbdao = new PuebloDAO();


    public SolicitudManagedBean() {
    }

    public String getSelectprov() {
        return selectprov;
    }

    public void setSelectprov(String selectprov) {
        this.selectprov = selectprov;
    }

    public String getSelectmun() {
        return selectmun;
    }

    public void setSelectmun(String selectmun) {
        this.selectmun = selectmun;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getSelectItemsOneProvincia() {
        this.selectItemsOneProvincia = new ArrayList<>();
        UbisolicDAO udao = new UbisolicDAO();
        List<Provincia> provincias = udao.allProv();
        selectItemsOneProvincia.clear();
        for (Provincia provincia : provincias) {
            SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem(provincia.getId(), provincia.getNomb_prov());
            this.selectItemsOneProvincia.add(selectItem);
        }
        System.out.println("Se cargaron provincias: " + selectItemsOneProvincia.size());
        return selectItemsOneProvincia;
    }

    public void setSelectItemsOneProvincia(List<SelectItem> selectItemsOneProvincia) {
        this.selectItemsOneProvincia = selectItemsOneProvincia;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getSelectItemsOneMunicipio() {
        if (selectprov != null && !selectprov.equals("")) {
            this.selectItemsOneMunicipio = new ArrayList<>();
            UbisolicDAO udao = new UbisolicDAO();
            List<Municipio> municipios = udao.listMunicipios(selectprov);
            selectItemsOneMunicipio.clear();
            for (Municipio municipio : municipios) {
                SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem(municipio.getId(), municipio.getNomb_mun());
                this.selectItemsOneMunicipio.add(selectItem);
            }
            System.out.println("Se cargaron municipios: " + selectItemsOneMunicipio.size());

        } else {
            this.selectItemsOneMunicipio = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return selectItemsOneMunicipio;
    }

    public void setSelectItemsOneMunicipio(List<SelectItem> selectItemsOneMunicipio) {
        this.selectItemsOneMunicipio = selectItemsOneMunicipio;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getSelectItemsOnePueblo() {
        if (selectprov != null && !selectprov.equals("")
                && selectmun != null && !selectmun.equals("")) {
            this.selectItemsOnePueblo = new ArrayList<>();
            UbisolicDAO udao = new UbisolicDAO();
            List<Pueblo> pueblos = udao.listPueblos(selectmun, selectprov);
            selectItemsOnePueblo.clear();
            for (Pueblo pueblo : pueblos) {
                SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem(pueblo.getId(), pueblo.getNomb_pueb());
                this.selectItemsOnePueblo.add(selectItem);
            }
            System.out.println("Se cargaron pueblos: " + selectItemsOnePueblo.size());

        } else {
            this.selectItemsOnePueblo = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return selectItemsOnePueblo;
    }

    public void setSelectItemsOnePueblo(List<SelectItem> selectItemsOnePueblo) {
        this.selectItemsOnePueblo = selectItemsOnePueblo;
    }

    public Solicitud getSelectsolicitud() {
        return selectsolicitud;
    }

    public void setSelectsolicitud(Solicitud selectsolicitud) {
        this.selectsolicitud = selectsolicitud;
    }

    public String getSelectpueblo() {
        return selectpueblo;
    }

    public void setSelectpueblo(String selectpueblo) {
        this.selectpueblo = selectpueblo;
    }

    public void addSolicitud() throws ParseException {
        SolicitudDAO sdao = new SolicitudDAO();
        String msg;
        long id_pueb = pbdao.getIdPueblo(selectpueblo).get(0);
        if (sdao.addSolicitud(this.selectsolicitud)) {

            msg = "Los datos se añadieron correctamente";
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, " ");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        } else {
            msg = "Error añadiendo el registro";
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, " ");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }
        selectsolicitud = new Solicitud();
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a SOe. He eliminado la información de contacto porque la pregunta se debe solucionar por este foro. En cuanto a la pregunta, una duda:¿al actualizar provincias sí te actualiza los municipios o no?

Comment: Y sobretodo, ¿por qué metes el `select` de Pueblo dentro de un `<p:row>` y un `<p:column>`? Eso tiene sentido dentro de un `<p:dataTable>`, pero no parece el caso...

Comment: @Jenice Tienes relacionados los campos en la base de datos?

Comment: Al seleccionar la Provincia se actualiza los Municipios pero cuando se selecciona un Municipio no se actualiza los Pueblos.

Comment: agregé un select dentro de un <p:row> y un <p:column> porque necesitaba agragar otras cosas y q me quedara dentro de esa celda en la tabla pero eso no tiene q ver con los select

Comment: Estas tablas si tienen relación en la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en el **update** `update="munlist"` por que en el bean no estas obteniendo el valor **selectprov** cambia tu ***update*** de la siguiente forma:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="provlist" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectprov}" style="width:130px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione la provincia" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectItemsOneProvincia}" />
    <p:ajax update="formDialog"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

O con `process="@form"` o **this** asi:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="provlist" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectprov}" style="width:130px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione la provincia" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectItemsOneProvincia}" />
    <p:ajax update="munlist" process="@form" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

O simplemente un update a los dos componentes así:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="provlist" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectprov}" style="width:130px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione la provincia" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectItemsOneProvincia}" />
    <p:ajax update="munlist provlist" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Esto lo arias en los demás **selectOneMenu**.

Y un ultimo consejo es que no fueran get los métodos y podrías hacer lo siguiente para mandarlos a llamar cuando los necesitas por ejemplo:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="provlist" value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectprov}" style="width:130px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione la provincia" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectItemsOneProvincia}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="munlist provlist" listener="#{solicitudManagedBean.selectItemsOneMunicipio}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>

public List<SelectItem> selectItemsOneMunicipio() {
    if (selectprov != null && !selectprov.equals("")) {
        this.selectItemsOneMunicipio = new ArrayList<>();
        UbisolicDAO udao = new UbisolicDAO();
        List<Municipio> municipios = udao.listMunicipios(selectprov);
        selectItemsOneMunicipio.clear();
        for (Municipio municipio : municipios) {
            SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem(municipio.getId(), municipio.getNomb_mun());
            this.selectItemsOneMunicipio.add(selectItem);
        }
        System.out.println("Se cargaron municipios: " + selectItemsOneMunicipio.size());

    } else {
        this.selectItemsOneMunicipio = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    return selectItemsOneMunicipio;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, pero todavía no se me actualizan los Pueblos, solo los Municipios cuando selecciono la Provincia.